# JSONPaths file: Parse a JSON object contained within a JSON array

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I have rows of the following JSON form:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "costs": [
      {
        "blue": 100,
        "location":"courts",
        "sport": "football"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to upload this into a redshift table as follows:

```
  id  | blue  | location | sport
--------+------+---------+------
   1  | 100   | courts    |football
```

The following JSONPaths file is not successful:

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$.id",
        "$.costs[0].blue",
        "$.costs[0].location",
        "$.costs[0].sport"
    ]
}
```

Redshift returns the following error code:

```
err_code: 1216 Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.
```

How can I change the jsonpaths file to be able to upload the json as desired?

Comment: I think it might be because your expression is not wrapped in `{}`, so it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. It worked after I removed the [] wrapped around the row. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is provided by [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) in the comments. I am just formalizing the answer here.

As shown in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json), the input JSON records have to be a new line delimited sequence of JSON objects. The examples show the JSON objects as pretty printed, but typically the input stream of records would be one JSON object per line.

```
{ "id": 1, "costs": [ { "blue": 100, "location":"courts", "sport": "football" } ] }
{ "id": 2, "costs": [ { "blue": 200, "location":"fields", "sport": "cricket" } ] }
```

So, technically the input record stream is not required to be a valid JSON, but a stream of delimited valid JSON objects.